# How do I implement this in standard Meteor without having to do weird hacks?

Tags: meteor

My sample app shows a d3js chart with meteor. The width, the height and the data can be changed by the user reactively.

The challenge is to refresh only the part of the chart that need a refresh.

I do this for fun to see how it can be implemented with Meteor reactivity because someone implemented it with Reactive.js here: http://eng.wealthfront.com/2013/04/reactive-charts-with-d3-and-reactivejs.html

You can try the app here: http://testd3js.meteor.com/

And the documented code is here: https://gist.github.com/tomsdev/5428018

The problem is: to have this working I have to use a hack that replace Session with a simpler object because we can't store a Function type in Session. I need to store the scale functions returned by d3js. I then use the scale functions as reactive dependencies to refresh the bars or the labels of the chart.

So, I was wondering if you could add the possibility of storing Function in Session or if there is an other way (without creating my own reactive data source)?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question... you have some input fields for the user to enter a specification of chart (for example, if the user enters "1,4,2" in the third input field, that means to have three boxes of relative heights 1, 4, and 2).  The goal is to  display the chart as specified by the user, and to do so reactively (the chart should change as the user changes the inputs).  Is this an accurate summary?

Comment: I think the part I'm not clear on is "the challenge is to refresh only the part of the chart that needs a refresh".  Can you give an specific example, such as the user changes their input from A to B and the goal is to refresh part X of the chart but not part Y?

Comment: The challenge is the same specified in the article from Wealthfront: to not refresh the whole graph but just the parts that need it. In this simplified example, there is not a lot of parts in the graph. For example you can change the Width and it won't compute again scaleY but only scaleX, bars and labels.

Comment: Oh, OK, the article says "Note that only the parts of our chart affected by a given change will be updated. In our example that's everything".  That's what was confusing me, I wasn't seeing an example a value that could change without needing to redraw the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in ReactiveVars, which can store functions. After adding the package with `meteor add reactive-var`:

```
var foo = new ReactiveVar;
foo.set(function(){});
foo.get(); // => function(){}
```